# Remove strings that contain a colon in R

Tags: r, string, replace

this an exemplary excerpt of my data set. It looks like as follows:

```
Description;ID;Date
wa119:d Here comes the first row;id_112;2018/03/02
ax21:3 Here comes the second row;id_115;2018/03/02
bC230:13 Here comes the third row;id_234;2018/03/02
```

I want to delete those words which contain a a colon. In this case, this would be wa119:d, ax21:3 and bC230:13 so that my new data set should look like as follows:

```
Description;ID;Date
Here comes the first row;id_112;2018/03/02
Here comes the second row;id_115;2018/03/02
Here comes the third row;id_234;2018/03/02
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a regular expression / solution with gsub? Can anyone help?

Comment: The third line of your example data contains two words with colons. Please clarify a bit your desired output in the text of your question.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the data frame accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
## reading in yor data
dat <- read.table(text ='
Description;ID;Date
wa119:d Here comes the first row;id_112;2018/03/02
ax21:3 Here comes the second row;id_115;2018/03/02
bC230:13 Here comes the third row;id:234;2018/03/02
', sep = ';', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## \\w+ = one or more word characters
gsub('\\w+:\\w+\\s+', '', dat$Description)

## [1] "Here comes the first row"  
## [2] "Here comes the second row"
## [3] "Here comes the third row"
```

More info on `\\w` a shorthand character class that is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`:https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: The output of your `gsub` construction does not seem to return the same value as the quoted desired input. OP is not clear on the actual structure of data and there is discrepancy with what is desired output.

Comment: Thanks! But how to remove the first space that is left when having removed the words with colon?

Comment: You could remove it via `gsub('\\w+:\\w+\\s+', '', dat$Description)` but not sure if that will work with your actually data.  I guess it depends on what your data looks like.  If the colon words always occur at the front of the string this problem gets easier.  If it always occurs at the begining I'd use a start of line anchor `^` like this `'^\\w+:\\w+\\s+'` as it is more explicit and likely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the column you want to modify is `dat`:

```
dat <- c("wa119:d Here comes the first row",
         "ax21:3 Here comes the second row",
         "bC230:13 Here comes the third row")
```

Then you can take each element, split it into words, remove the words containing a colon, and then paste what's left back together, yielding what you want:

```
dat_colon_words_removed <- unlist(lapply(dat, function(string){
  words <- strsplit(string, split=" ")[[1]]
  words <- words[!grepl(":", words)]
  paste(words, collapse=" ")
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that will exactly match expected result from OP could be as:

```
#data
df <- read.table(text = "Description;ID;Date
wa119:d Here comes the first row;id_112;2018/03/02
ax21:3 Here comes the second row;id_115;2018/03/02
bC230:13 Here comes the third row;id:234;2018/03/02", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="\n")

gsub("[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s", "", df$V1)

#[1] "Description;ID;Date"                        
#[2] "Here comes the first row;id_112;2018/03/02" 
#[3] "Here comes the second row;id_115;2018/03/02"
#[4] "Here comes the third row;id:234;2018/03/02"
```